# "Read-only property" error when using QQmlListProperty with custom class in QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am following the example at [qt-project.org](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-chapter6-plugins-example.html) to expose a custom type as a QQmlListProperty in QML.  At runtime, when initializing the list property, I get the error `Invalid property assignment: "overlayImages" is a read-only property`.

This is what I want to do in QML:

```
TestPattern {
    id: pattern

    overlayImages: [
        OverlayImage {
            x: 100
            y: 100
            alpha: 0.1
            source: "../../images/fail.png"
            visible: true
        }
    ]
}
```

Here are my custom type declarations:

```
class TestPatternQuickPrivate;
class QMLTESTPATTERN_EXPORT TestPatternQuick : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(TestPatternQuick)
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(TestPatternQuick)
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<OverlayImage> overlayImages READ overlayImages)

public:
    TestPatternQuick(QQuickItem *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    virtual ~TestPatternQuick();    
    QQmlListProperty<OverlayImage> overlayImages();

private:
    static void appendOverlayImage(QQmlListProperty<OverlayImage> *list, OverlayImage *overlayImage);
    QScopedPointer<TestPatternQuickPrivate> d_ptr; //QScopedPointer guarantees no throw
};

class OverlayImagePrivate;
class QMLTESTPATTERN_EXPORT OverlayImage : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(OverlayImage)

public:
    OverlayImage(QQuickItem *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    OverlayImage(const OverlayImage &other);
    virtual ~OverlayImage();
    OverlayImage &operator=(const OverlayImage &other);

private:
    QScopedPointer<OverlayImagePrivate> d_ptr; //QScopedPointer guarantees no throw
};
```

...and C++ plugin registration implementation:

```
void QmlTestPatternPlugin::registerTypes(const char *uri)
{
    qmlRegisterType<TestPatternQuick>(uri, 1 /*major*/, 0 /*minor*/, "TestPattern");
    qmlRegisterType<OverlayImage>(uri, 1 /*major*/, 0 /*minor*/, "OverlayImage");
}
```

Can anyone shed light on what I'm still missing?

Comment: I'd look into http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-referenceexamples-properties-example.html, and compare...

Comment: I had a similar problem when my property was defined inside the namespace. To resolve it I've added a namespace to object inside Q_PROPERTY macro

Comment: @Zak thank you *SO* much, I spent the last hour going crazy about this issue. For it to work one need the fully qualified name inside `Q_PROPERTY` like `Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<foo::bar::Baz> quxx READ quxx)`